# How to show username field in keystonejs Admin UI during add/edit user?

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I wanted to show the username in the Admin UI in keystonejs during add/edit user. I have added the username and other fiedls in User model like following but they are not displaying in the Admin UI.

`User.add({
    username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true, index: true, default: ''},
    name: {type: Types.Name, required: true, index: true},
    email: {type: Types.Email, initial: true, required: true, index: true},
    password: {type: Types.Password, initial: true, required: true},
    resetPasswordKey: {type: String, hidden: true},
    homeawayAccessToken:{type: String, hidden: true, default: ''},
    homeawayRefreshToken:{type: String, hidden: true, default: ''},
    homeawayTokenExpiresIn:{type: Number, hidden: true, default: ''}
}, 'Permissions', {
    isAdmin: {type: Boolean, label: 'Can access Keystone', index: true}
});`

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add an 'initial: true' parameter to fields you want in the create UX screen
...

```
User.add({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true, 
    unique: true,
    index: true,
    default: '',
    initial: true
  },...
});
```